# Ytplayer in listview on scroll audio get distracted

Tags: android, listview, ytplayer

I am playing youtube videos in listview using ytplayer and it is playing successfully but the issue is : when i start youtube video and scroll the list, the audio is distracted. I think the reason is reusing of views. But i could not find the way to get smooth audio even on scrolling. Any help would be highly appreciated.